# How can i save the class when navigating to another page? Maybe using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

The JS code I have now:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".cardButton");
let favoritesCount = document.getElementById("favCount");
let currentCount = localStorage.getItem("currentCount") || 11;
localStorage.setItem("currentCount", currentCount);
favoritesCount.textContent = currentCount;

buttons.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currentCount = localStorage.getItem("currentCount");
        if (elem.textContent == "В избранное") {
            elem.textContent = "В избранном";
            currentCount++;
            favoritesCount.textContent = currentCount;
            localStorage.setItem( "currentCount" , currentCount.toString());
        } else {
            elem.textContent = "В избранное";
            currentCount--;
            favoritesCount.textContent = currentCount;
            localStorage.setItem( "currentCount" , currentCount.toString());
        }
        elem.classList.toggle("button-blue");
        elem.classList.toggle("card-favorites-selected-button");
        localStorage.setItem(elem, elem.textContent);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(elem));
        console.log(currentCount);
    })
});
```

It changes classes for pressed buttons and changes the counter of selected items. But I need that when I go to another page and back, the classes that were selected before were selected. What ideas do you have?

Comment: Did you try using localStorage? What happened?

Comment: @mykaf Oh yes i am using localStorage to keep the count of selected items. But I don't know what logic to use to keep the selected buttons having an "active" class. Now it looks like this for me: I have 4 product cards with buttons to add to favorites, when I click "to favorites", the counter increases and the class of this button changes. When I go to another page and back, the counter is saved, since I made it through localStorage, and the classes of all buttons are again "inactive" and I can infinitely increase the counter this way)

Comment: Perhaps you should read up on [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [DomTokenList.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add).